# TCP Packet editing on Android

Tags: android, tcp, root, editing, packet

I'm trying to write an android application (or service, commandline tool etc.), which monitors the TCP traffic of one specific app and drops a packet if needed. On windows I could do this by hooking the send() and recv() calls in the targeted process. The purpose behind that is that my app should monitor the traffic of WhatsApp Messenger and stops it from notifying the server when I was online.
But I couldn't figure out how I can monitor and edit packets on a rooted android phone.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can read all the data that is flowing though the mobile using :

[libpcap for android](https://github.com/android/platform_external_libpcap)

However, In order to monitor traffic of a specific application , you'll need to parse the HTTP data by reading packet . You can read about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2768724/776765

Also, Whatsapp conversation are encrypted with the new version.You can read it in [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WhatsApp).