# Printing http field values

Tags: http, url, packet-capture

In packet sniffer, coded using C, is it possible to print the URL from a captured HTTP packet?
Is there a way to exactly locate the URL field from the TCP/UDP payload?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703238/how-to-hijack-all-local-http-request-and-extract-the-url-using-c/

Comment: Yes! Thanks a ton!!